# What type does std::find_if_not() return?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl, iterator

I'm stuck when doing an exercise from the book *C++ Primer* , which goes:

> Exercise 10.24:Use bind and check_size to find the first element in a
>   vector of ints that has a value greater than the length of a specified
>   string value.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

bool check_size(const std::string &s, std::string::size_type sz)
{
   return s.size() > sz;
}

std::vector<int>::iterator
find_first_bigger(const std::vector<int> &v, const std::string &s);

int main(){return 0;}

std::vector<int>::iterator
find_first_bigger(const std::vector<int> &v, const std::string &s)
{
    auto it= std::find_if_not(v.begin(), v.end(),std::bind(check_size,s,std::placeholders::_1));
    return it;
}
```

When trying to compile, the compiler complained that:

> `error: could not convert 'it' from '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const
>   int*, std::vector<int> >' to 'std::vector<int>::iterator {aka
>   __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >}'`

To find out what is going on,I turned to the header *stl_algo.h* in which I guess std::find_if_not is defined.The comment there said:

> @return   The first iterator @c i in the range @p [_*first,*_last)

The definition of this function:

```
template<typename _InputIterator, typename _Predicate>
inline _InputIterator
find_if_not(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
    _Predicate __pred)
{
  // concept requirements
  __glibcxx_function_requires(_InputIteratorConcept<_InputIterator>)
  __glibcxx_function_requires(_UnaryPredicateConcept<_Predicate,
      typename iterator_traits<_InputIterator>::value_type>)
  __glibcxx_requires_valid_range(__first, __last);
  return std::__find_if_not(__first, __last, __pred);
}
```

It seems the return type should be the same to the argument.But why complier complained so? How to fix this error?Thx.

Comment: `iterator` isn't the same as `const_iterator`. You can't get an `iterator` from a constant vector.

Comment: Another abuse of `auto`?  `auto` is fine for the control variable of a for loop, where the variables declared don't have scope outside of the for loop, but it's use more generally should be considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: @JamesKanze So..do you mean this way is better: **std::vector<int>::iterator it= std::find_if_not(v.begin(), v.end(),std::bind(check_size,s,std::placeholders::_1));** ? If so, can you tell me more why this way is better? I just began learning C++, really need this kind of suggestion.

Comment: @AlanWang In this case, definitely yes.  The type _is_ important here (and you would have gotten the error on the initialization of `it`), and you should specify it, even if it is a bit verbose.  About the only time where you want to use `auto` is in hand written loops, where the type doesn't propagate, and the variable is only used as a classic iterator (comparison with `container.end()`, dereference, increment).

Comment: @JamesKanze Thanks for your clear explanation.I'll notice this thing later on. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::vector<int>::iterator
find_first_bigger(const std::vector<int> &v, const std::string &s);
                   ^^
```

Your vector is const. So you'll get a `std::vector<int>::const_iterator`.
Had it not been const, you'd get a `std::vector<int>::iterator`

Answer (score 3):

Notice

```
//...
inline _InputIterator
find_if_not(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
    _Predicate __pred)
//...
```

returns the same type of iterator that it receives as a parameter.

Since you passed a `const std::vector<int> &v` you must return a `const_iterator` thus

```
std::vector<int>::const_iterator
find_first_bigger(const std::vector<int> &v, const std::string &s);
```